# Retreive geolocated images depending on users location

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, core-location, geofire

What is some code I could use to retrieve geolocated images uploaded by users with GeoFire depending on the users location?

What would be the first steps to follow? Is actually GeoFire the best way to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Once you have tried the GeoFire examples and created a version of your code based on them, please ask us here if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GeoFire is the usual tool to achieve the goal you describe: store and retrieve information based on its position, asuming you are already familiar with Firebase and using it as your backend

The first steps to follow should be to read the Geoquery quickstart and try the examples you can find in their documentation: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/tree/master/GeoFire

You can see a more complete example here (although it is in Objective-C):

https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/tree/master/examples/SFVehicles

Once you have tried the examples you will have an idea of how you can use GeoFire to achieve your goal.